# Binding Variable PyQt Radio Buttons

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtgui

I am using PyQt4 and want to set up a list of radio buttons that set a variable value dependent on the selection. Obviously I can do it with a ton of IF statements (10 radio buttons) but I figured there must be an elegant way to do it.

To clarify in psuedocode:

```
radiobutton1 = 52
radiobutton2 = 31
radiobutton3 = 773

if radiobutton1 x = 52
if radiobutton2 x = 31
if radiobutton3 x = 773
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this or something similar, iterating through your widget set:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    widgetname = 'radiobutton' + str(i)
    if widgetname.isChecked():
    return widgetname.value
```

You could also set up the set of radio buttons in a list and iterate
through this list of objects rather than using string manipulations.
Example:

```
rb_list = [ rb1, rb2, rb3 ] # where items are your radio buttons
#these can be appended to the list when the objects are created
def rb_check(rbl=rb_list):
    for rb in rbl:
        if rb.isChecked():
            print("RadioButton", rb, "is checked.") # or return value
```

Hope that helps.